# converting a dictionary to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary as follows :

```
{'result': '{"maid":{"0":"0365206d-e97d-4ab0-aa63-64091e66a1a4","1":"0955bbcc-3a83-4c64-8170-f5deb799a5ba","2":"0570ba29-1ee8-4bc6-a12c-c2b706d805c8"},"category":{"0":"EventHall","1":"SuperMarket","2":"Bank"},"geo_behavior":{"0":null,"1":null,"2":null},"polygonid":{"0":2332,"1":2332,"2":2332},"places":{"0":"Shri Sai Dj","1":"D Mart","2":"Bank of Baroda"},"age":{"0":38.0,"1":18.0,"2":37.0},"gender":{"0":0.0,"1":0.0,"2":0.0},"mobile":{"0":null,"1":null,"2":null},"make":{"0":"oppo","1":"vivo","2":"oneplus"},"deviceprice":{"0":160.0,"1":190.0,"2":392.0},"weight":{"0":2.5684166749,"1":2.0,"2":2.0},"__index_level_0__":{"0":0,"1":1,"2":2}}'}
```

I am trying to parse this dictionary as a dataframe.  I tried the following:

```
l=k.get("result")
m=json.loads(l)
maid=m.get('maid')
cate=m.get('category')
geobh=m.get('geo_behavior')
pid=m.get('polygonid')
places=m.get('places')
age=m.get('age')
gender=m.get('gender')
mobile=m.get('mobile')
make=m.get('make')
deviceprice=m.get('deviceprice')
weight=m.get('weight')
```

this gives me individual dictionaries to merge to form a dataframe.  I also tried

```
pd.json_normalize
pd.DataFrame.from_records(
```

but not helping.  I am wondering if there is a simpler method to convert the `result` to a dictionary.

Comment: How did you use `pd.DataFrame.from_records`? `.from_records(m)` looks right, though the order changed.

Comment: @wjandrea Thank you for your message.  I passed on the dict named m with, m.keys() attribute as cols

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use pandas `read_json` to read `result` node and load it to a df like so:

```
import pandas as pd
json_ = {} # your json/dictionary 
df = pd.read_json(json_['result'])
print(df.head)
```

output:

```
                                   maid     category  geo_behavior  polygonid              places  age  gender  mobile     make  deviceprice    weight     __index_level_0__  
0  0365206d-e97d-4ab0-aa63-64091e66a1a4    EventHall           NaN       2332         Shri Sai Dj   38       0     NaN     oppo          160  2.568417                     0  
1  0955bbcc-3a83-4c64-8170-f5deb799a5ba  SuperMarket           NaN       2332              D Mart   18       0     NaN     vivo          190  2.000000                     1  
2  0570ba29-1ee8-4bc6-a12c-c2b706d805c8         Bank           NaN       2332      Bank of Baroda   37       0     NaN  oneplus          392  2.000000                     2  


[3 rows x 12 columns]
```